# Ruby On Rails: Text form - how to change fields to required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actually, I have a little issue. I have a form where you can pick a name and so on. One is a text field, the other ones are select. I can change text field to required which means that you need to write something into it, but how can I do it with the other ones?

It's not a problem that I can add the user instead, but if I try to delete the user, I'm in trouble with this error:

```
Couldn't find Key with 'id'=
Extracted source (around line #51):

49  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
50  if @student
51      Key.find(@student.key_id).update(student_id: 0)
52      Harddrive.find(@student.harddrive_id).update(student_id: 0)
53  end
54  @student.destroy
```

And this is the code of my form:

```
<%= form_for @student, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label 'Account' %>
    <%= f.text_field :account, :class => "form-control form-control-text", :required => true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label 'Operating system' %>
    <%= f.select :os, '<option value="linux">Linux</option><option value="windows">Windows</option>'.html_safe, 
        {include_blank: false}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label 'Hard drive' %>
    <%= f.select :harddrive_id, Harddrive.where(student_id: 0).map { |drive| [drive.name, drive.id] }, 
        {include_blank: false}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label 'Key' %>
    <%= f.select :key_id, Key.where(student_id: 0).map { |key| [key.name, key.id] }, {include_blank: false}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label 'Pawn' %>
    <%= f.select :pawn, '<option value="true">Paid</option><option value="false">Not paid</option>'.html_safe,
            {include_blank: false}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label 'Comment' %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment, :class => "form-control form-control-text" %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit (f.object.new_record? ? 'Create' : 'Update'), :class => "btn btn-outline-dark" %>
<% end %>
```

Cheers,
absolado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid exception, just modify code as follows:

```
@student = Student.find(params[:id])
if @student
  Key.find(@student.key_id).update(student_id: 0) if @student.key_id.present?
  Harddrive.find(@student.harddrive_id).update(student_id: 0)
end
@student.destroy
```

Or you can add required validation from model itself for `key_id`

```
class Student
  validates :key_id, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's now working as it should. Do you also know how I can set the select fields also to required as I did with the text field?